# Float left <li> + transition on height = issues

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-transitions

I am applying a transition hover effect that causes the `<li>` to enlarge.

Problem is the `last child` on ever row, when hovered over, pushes the next 2 `<li>` below several spaces to the right.

Any way I can keep this from happening? I'm kinda new to using transitions and have been racking my brain trying to see if this can be fixed.

Thanks!

**CSS**

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
width: 985px;
min-height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

ul #fourbox {
list-style-type: none;
}

#fourbox li {
display: block;
width: 188px;
height: 213px;
margin: 15px 10px;
padding: 15px;
background: #F1F1F2;
border: 1px solid #D1D2D4;
float: left;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #888888;
transition:all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

#fourbox li:hover {
width: 198px;
height: 228px;
margin: 5px 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px #888888;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul id="fourbox">
        <li>
            <p>1</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>2</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>3</p>
        </li>   
        <li>
            <p>4</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>5</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>6</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>7</p>
        </li>   
        <li>
            <p>8</p>
            </li>               
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Refer: **http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/mVrMH/**

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pehD/)

Comment: inline-block worked! Thank you all so much! What a great and speedy community!

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to the site so I'll do just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution:

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SCsKH/)

Use `display:inline-block` as opposed to `float:left`

```
#fourbox li {
    width: 188px;
    height: 213px;
    margin: 15px 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #F1F1F2;
    border: 1px solid #D1D2D4;
    display:inline-block;                     /* ADD THIS <<< */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #888888;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use `clear:both` if you need to float them.

Either solutions work. Nice little animation though!

Answer (score 2):

Remove "float:left" and replace that "display:block" with "display:inline-block"...

```
#fourbox li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 188px;
    height: 213px;
    margin: 15px 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #F1F1F2;
    border: 1px solid #D1D2D4;

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #888888;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/sAmxE/**

Hope that works for you!

Answer (score 2):

```
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #wrapper {
            width: 985px;
            min-height: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;

        }

        ul #fourbox {
            list-style-type: none;
            display: block;
        }

        #fourbox li {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 188px;
            height: 213px;
            margin: 15px 10px;
            padding: 15px;
            background: #F1F1F2;
            border: 1px solid #D1D2D4;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #888888;
            transition:all 0.5s ease;
            -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
        }

        #fourbox li:hover {
            width: 198px;
           height: 228px;
            margin: 5px 5px;
            box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px #888888;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul id="fourbox">
            <li>
                <p>1</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>2</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>3</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>4</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>5</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>6</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>7</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>8</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

. Just made few changes and its working

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it, it looks like you're trying to keep it to 3 boxes per row, right?  If that's the case, you could simply use a clear:both; between each set of 3.

Works for me here.  http://jsfiddle.net/Tzh8b/

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to give the elements more breathing room for that extra space or use JS to decrease the %(assuming they are 50%s) of all li and than add the hover effect on $(this) li so when you hover over an li you than decrease all the other lis allowing for enough room for it to grow.

so `$("li").hover(function() {
$("li").css('width','smaller'); 
$(this).css('width','larger');
});`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using actual widths and heights why not use CSS Transforms! They're neat :)

```
transform:scale(1.1);
```

or for webkit

```
-webkit- transform:scale(1.1);
```

It doesnt affect normal flow and is easy to implement :) Let me know if this works for you!

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/eYCQq/